# Change images with left and right arrows

Tags: javascript

I have a gallery which changes the images with onclick but I also want images to get change with left and right arrow control.

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Below is the javascript which I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.gallerySplash = function(){
    var object = $(this),
        imageHolder = $("#imageHolder",object),
        image = $("#imageHolder > img",object),
        imageSRCLink = $("ul>li>a",object),
        imageDeltaX,
        imageDeltaY,
        imageK =image.height()/image.width(),
        holderK =imageHolder.height()/imageHolder.width(),
        imagePercent = (image.height()/image.width())*100,
        imgSRC,
        currImg = 0,
        prevImg = 0,
        allImg = imageSRCLink.length,
        autoPlayState = false,
        autoPlayTime = 8,
        loadComplete = true,
        doc=$(document),
        openGall = false,
        MSIE8 = ($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version <= 8);

    init()

    function init(){
        $(window).resize(resizeImageHandler).trigger('resize');
        $(window).bind("hashchange", changeHash);
        $("#next").bind("mousedown", function(){
            changePreviewPosition(-1);
            return false;           
        });
        $("#prev").bind("mousedown", function(){
            changePreviewPosition(1);
            return false;           
        });
        $("window, document, #prev, #next, body, #wrapper").bind("mouseup", function(){
            stopPreviewPosition();
            return false;           
        });
        $("#prev, #next").click(
            function(){
                return false;           
            }
        )
        $("#closeGallery").click(function(){
            if(openGall){
                openGall = false;
                $("#previewHolder").stop().animate({left:45}, 500, "easeInOutCubic");
                if(!MSIE8){
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition:"3px 14px"}).stop().animate({scale:1}, 0).css({left:"192px", top:"50%"});
                 }
            }else{
                openGall = true;
                $("#previewHolder").stop().animate({left:245}, 500, "easeInOutCubic");
                if(!MSIE8){
                    $(this).css({backgroundPosition:"14px 14px"}).stop().animate({scale:-1}, 0).css({left:"192px", top:"50%"});
                }
            }
            return false;           
        }).hover(
            function(){
                if(openGall){
                    $(this).stop(true).animate({left:187}, 250, "easeOutExpo")
                }else{
                    $(this).stop(true).animate({left:197}, 250, "easeOutExpo")  
                }
            },
            function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({left:192}, 250, "easeOutExpo")
            }
        );
        $("#previewHolder ul>li>a").each(function(){
            $(this).append("<div class='over'></div>")
            $(".over", this).animate({opacity:0}, 150, "easeInOutCubic")
        }).click(
            function(){
                if($(this).parent().index()!=currImg && loadComplete){
                    $("#previewHolder ul>li").eq(currImg).find("a>.over").stop(true).animate({opacity:0}, 150, "easeInOutCubic")
                    currImg=$(this).parent().index();
                    changeImageHandler();
                    $("#imageCaption").html($(this).attr('title'));
                }
                return false;           
            }
        ).hover(
            function(){
                if($(this).parent().index()!=currImg){
                    $(".over", this).stop(true).animate({opacity:1}, 300, "easeInOutCubic")
                }
            },
            function(){
                if($(this).parent().index()!=currImg){
                    $(".over", this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 300, "easeInOutCubic")
                }
            }
        );
        $("#previewHolder ul>li").eq(currImg).find("a>.over").stop().animate({opacity:1}, 0)
        autoPlayHandler();
    }
    function changeHash(){
        if(window.location.hash.substring(3, window.location.hash.length)==$("#menu dd").eq(0).attr("id") && !openGall){
            openGall = true;
            $("#previewHolder").stop().animate({left:245}, 500, "easeInOutCubic")
            if(!MSIE8){
                $("#closeGallery").css({backgroundPosition:"14px 14px"}).stop().animate({scale:-1}, 0).css({left:"192px", top:"50%"});
            }
        }
    }
    function changePreviewPosition(number){
        var innerH = $("#inner").height(),
            ulH =  $("#inner>ul").height(),
            scrollTime;         
        if(number==-1){
            scrollTime = Math.abs(parseInt($("#inner>ul").css("top"))*5000/(ulH-innerH));
            $("#inner>ul").stop(true).animate({top:0}, scrollTime, "linear");   
        }else{
            scrollTime = Math.abs((parseInt($("#inner>ul").css("top"))+(ulH-innerH))*5000/(ulH-innerH));
            $("#inner>ul").stop(true).animate({top:-(ulH-innerH)}, scrollTime, "linear");
        }
    }
    function stopPreviewPosition(){
        $("#inner>ul").stop(true)
    }   
    function autoPlayHandler(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(autoPlayState){
                prevImg = currImg;
                currImg++
                if(currImg>=allImg){
                    currImg = 0 
                }
                changeImageHandler()
            }
        }, autoPlayTime*1000)
    }
    function resizeImageHandler(){
        image = $("#imageHolder > img");
        imageK =image.height()/image.width()
        holderK =doc.height()/doc.width();
        if(holderK>imageK){
        }else{
        }
        imageDeltaX=0//-(image.width()-doc.width())/2;
        imageDeltaY=-(image.height()-doc.height())/2;
        image.css({left:imageDeltaX, position:"absolute"});
    }
    function changeImageHandler(){
        loadComplete = false;
        image.addClass("topImg");
        imgSRC = imageSRCLink.eq(currImg).attr("href");
        imageHolder.append("<div id='imgSpinner'></div><img class='bottomImg' src="+imgSRC+" alt=''>");
        $("#imgSpinner").css({opacity:0}).stop().animate({opacity:0.5}, 500, "easeInOutCubic");
        $(".bottomImg").bind("load", loadImageHandler)
    }
    function loadImageHandler(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".bottomImg").unbind("load", loadImageHandler);
            $("#imgSpinner").stop().animate({opacity:"0"}, 1000, "easeInOutCubic")
            resizeImageHandler();
            $(".topImg").stop().animate({opacity:"0"}, 1000, "easeInOutCubic", function(){
                $("#imgSpinner").remove();
                $(".topImg").remove();
                image.removeClass("bottomImg");
                loadComplete = true;
                autoPlayHandler()
            })
        }, 1000)
    }
}
})
```

With the help of your code I did this and it worked for me but still creating some issue. It's working only one time not changing the currImg indexing please help me in this.

You can check the live version here: http://www.solvonix.co.in/clients/demo/

Revised code is :

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
 if (event.which == 37) {
// left arrow; go back
currImg=$(this).parent().index();
 currImg--
 if(currImg<=0){
  currImg = 0 
 }    
 changeImageHandler();
 }
 if (event.which == 39) {
currImg=$(this).parent().index();
 currImg++
 prevImg = currImg
 if(currImg>=allImg){
  currImg = allImg 
 }
                                    currImg++
 changeImageHandler();
// right arrow; go forward
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

try putting this code in the `init()` function

```
$('window').live('keypress', function (e) {
   if ( e.keyCode == 37 ){
       changePreviewPosition(1); //left key
       return false;
    }
   if ( e.keyCode == 39 ){
       changePreviewPosition(-1); //right key
       return false;
    }
})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I am quite close to the solution. I have updated the problem below with a link to my live website. I want images to get change with left and right arrow. Please check what wrong I am doing. Thanks again for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
  if (event.which == 37) {
    // left arrow; go back
    changePreviewPosition(1)
  }
  if (event.which == 39) {
    // right arrow; go forward
    changePreviewPosition(-1)
  }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, you have provided good piece of code. But I want to change the images of the gallery while your code is dragging the entire gallery to the last image. Please check the updated version here: http://www.solvonix.co.in/clients/demo/#!/about-me-page